# C# WPF POST Request to php file on https site on strato server not working

Tags: c#, php, https, http-post

I want to post one or more values to a php file on a strato (the host) server on a https domain using a C# WPF desktop application. However, after several attempts with a test program nothing seems to work. The testing value is not posted to the server, the `$_POST` Array is empty, respectively. I do get an echoed answer from the server but its always 'Error' (See script below).

I did try this with several techniques as well:

- `Webclient` / `HttpClient`
- `HttpWebRequest`
- Adjusting `SecurityProtocolType`
- sending value as `byte[]`

and what not.

`$_GET` by the way works perfectly fine as I always get back the computed testing value from the php script. However, I would like to have a POST Request since I am sending user data to the server.

More precisely, I already have tried these solutions (and several similar ones):

- [How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request) (basically all of them except 3rd Party)
- [C# HttpClient not sending POST variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375650/c-sharp-httpclient-not-sending-post-variables)
- https://holger.coders-online.net/118
- http://www.howtosolvenow.com/how-to-send-https-post-request-with-c/

Testing PHP Script:

```
$newnumber = 'Error';
if(isset($_POST['number']))
{
    $newnumber = $_POST['number']+1;
}
echo $newnumber;
//keeps on returning 'Error'
```

Latest attempt of C# code:

```
string resultString = null;
string _url = "https://myURL.com/test.php";

//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("number", "2"),
});

var response = await client.PostAsync(_url, content);

resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

this._txt.Text = resultString;
```

Comment: Could this be some CORS issue ? Are you able to send POST data with Postman ?

Comment: Postman apparently does return the correct value

Comment: Today I also had this problem at Strato. In the end I figured out Strato removed all the post parameters when using http instead of https.